# Finding area of largest rectangular that fits on a series of rectangulars

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry, pseudocode

While studying I have stumbled upon an interesting problem and I am stuck.

We have a series of rectangles (base of each is 1) with varying heights, and we want to calculate area of biggest rectangle we could fit on them.

Attaching an image that I think reassembles this problem, area of red rectangles is what we want to find.

Now, I haven't yet taken DS class yet but learned some on my own, however I can't seem to find any fast solution for that. Heights can be big, like +million big, as well as total number of rectangles. Could anyone offer some guidelines please?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otvge.jpg

Comment: can you sort them? is it have to fit from the lower left point?

Comment: They are like physical objects so you can't really sort them, it doesn't have to fit from any particular point, it just has to be largest, so it can for example be a single building if its tall enough.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i have an idea. How about you:

1. Keep track of the lowest height you've seen so far. This starts at infinity.
2. Keep track of the number of rectangles you have seen so far, starts at 0.
3. Keep track of the highest area so far, this starts at 0.
4. While there is more rectangles

   1. Pick the next one
   2. lowest = min(current+lowest)
   3. count += 1
   4. max_area = max(max_area, lowest*count)

As an optimization, at some point you can compute that the remaining rectangles will not surpass your max area given your current, lowest boundary.

*Note, this is not the exact solution, as you could discard an arbitrary number of rectangles from the beginning too, but I think this is a good general approach. Will try to extend it later if I have time.*

---

Edit: Had further insight into it, but will leave the answer above as a "special" case solution, since it's also good. Now for the actual solution:

1. The limiting factor of your problem is the shortest rectangle. The area of that one will be multiplied by the total number of rectangles.
2. If you decide NOT to include that rectangle, you can opt for a better height and potentially a higher area.
3. Thus, the lowest rectangle effectively partitions your array in 2 sub-sets. To its right and to its left.
4. You can the consider each of these the same problem and do a recursive call.
5. Your method should then

   1. If called for a single rectangle, return its area
   2. Look for the smallest rectangle in the range.
   3. Recursively call to the left
   4. Recursively call to the right
   5. Return the biggest result between right, left and smallest*range

This should be O(n2) worst case (rectangles are sorted by height), but be O(NlogN) in the general case. It would use at most O(logN) memory when computing at the bottom of the branch.

Not sure it can be done better due to the nature of the problem ;-)

Comment: If I got your point, you will fail if the first rectangular's height is 1 and the next one is 1000

Comment: Exactly, the trivial thing would be to keep N-1 counts: "what happens if I skip 1, 2, ...", but uses too much memory. SO I'll try to think of something elegant.

Comment: Looks about right to me, and O(NlongN) as suggested. Is a further improvement by keeping track of "bestSoFar" and culling the search tree when simple tests limit what a branch can yield? There might be some O(N) pre-processing to help define bounds in ranges.

Comment: Not sure that can happen, per your description, a single rectangle can be the infinitely high and win alone. I imagine you could find the max along with the min for any range, and prune the search with that info in mind (if size of left/range range times biggest height found is less than shortest*range.size), but unless rectangles are fairly similar I don't imagine it would prune much. Code it and run some scenarios! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple linear solution:

1. Let's assume that the position of the lowest rectangle is fixed. What do we want to do then? Well, we want to find how far to the left and to the right we can go until we find a lower rectangle(let's call this positions `L` and `R`). If we know them, we can just multiply the width of all rectangle from `L` to `R` the by the the height of this rectangle and update the answer.
2. The part with the width is easy: we can use prefix sums.
3. Now let's find the leftmost lower rectangle located to the right from the given one in linear time(in total). Here is a pseudo code for this part:

   ```
   s = empty stack
   L = new int[n]
   fill(L, -1)
   for i <- 0 ... n - 1
       while !s.isEmpty() && s.peek().first >= h[i]
           s.pop()
       if !s.isEmpty() 
           L[i] = s.peek().second
       s.push((h[i], i)
   ```
4. Now we can reverse the array and compute `R[i]` for all `i` in the same.
5. When we have `L`, `R`, and prefix sums, we can just iterate over all rectangles to get the answer:

   ```
   for i <- 0 ... n - 1
       height = h[i]
       width = getWidth(L[i], R[i]) // we use prefix sums in getWidth
       res = max(res, height * width)
   ```

That's it.

Comment: Does not seem to work. For instance, the height sequence {3,2,4} produces L = {0, -1, 1}. Problems is, there is a conflict for pushing and pulling into the stack. I understand you idea of having, for each rectangle, how far I can go in either direction till I find something smaller than me. It's a good one, but I'm not sure you can keep it in a stack, as whatever you popped will not be available for the next rectangle you evaluate, which height can be the highest or lowest so far. Without this trick, you would just need to look back on the array, and that would make the algorithm O(N^2) :-(

Comment: @Daniel No, for `{3, 2, 4}` the `L` is `{-1, -1, 1}`. It is possible to prove that if we pop an element, we can throw it way and forget about it(proof idea: if we throw it away, there is a smaller element to the right from it. Thus, we will never need it in the future). So there is no pushing/popping conflict.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood, but you proof explains it well. It is similar to the first idea I had, but complete. It uses twice as much memory as the input though, which I was trying to avoid (memory had been my main bottleneck these days). But yeah, nice!